# Computing the derivative of the Gaussian function

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, implicit-differentiation, chain-rule, gaussian

I'm confused with a really stupid issue, namely computing by hand the first derivative of a Gaussian

$\displaystyle f{{\left({x}\right)}}={e}^{{-{\left(\frac{x}{{{x}_{{0}}}}\right)}^{{{2}{n}}}}}$

The n in the exponent is included, because I actually need a [super-Gaussian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function#Higher-order_Gaussian_or_super-Gaussian_function) for approximating a blurred rectangle function. Depending on how I write down the function, I'm getting three different results, which obviously cannot be correct:

1.:
$\displaystyle f{{\left({x}\right)}}={e}^{{-{\left(\frac{x}{{{x}_{{0}}}}\right)}^{{{2}{n}}}}}\Rightarrow{f}'{\left({x}\right)}=\frac{d}{{\left.{d}{x}\right.}}{e}^{{-{\left(\frac{x}{{{x}_{{0}}}}\right)}^{{{2}{n}}}}}=-{2}{n}{\left(\frac{x}{{x}_{{0}}}\right)}^{{{2}{n}}}\frac{1}{{x}}{e}^{{-{\left(\frac{x}{{{x}_{{0}}}}\right)}^{{{2}{n}}}}}$

2.:
$\displaystyle f{{\left({z}\right)}}={e}^{{-{z}^{{{2}{n}}}}}\Rightarrow{f}'{\left({z}\right)}=-{2}{n}{z}^{{{2}{n}-{1}}}{e}^{{-{z}^{{{2}{n}}}}}=-{2}{n}{\left(\frac{x}{{{x}_{{0}}}}\right)}^{{{2}{n}-{1}}}{e}^{{-{\left(\frac{x}{{{x}_{{0}}}}\right)}^{{{2}{n}}}}}$

3.: $\displaystyle f{{\left({x}\right)}}={\left({e}^{{{x}^{{{2}{n}}}}}\right)}^{{-\frac{1}{{{{x}_{{0}}^{{{2}{n}}}}}}}}\Rightarrow{f}'{\left({x}\right)}=\frac{d}{{\left.{d}{x}\right.}}{\left({e}^{{{x}^{{{2}{n}}}}}\right)}^{{-\frac{1}{{{{x}_{{0}}^{{{2}{n}}}}}}}}\\=\frac{d}{{{d}{\left(-\frac{1}{{{{x}_{{0}}^{{{2}{n}}}}}}\right)}}}{\left[\frac{d}{{{d}{\left(\frac{d}{{\left.{d}{x}\right.}}{x}^{{{2}{n}}}\right)}}}{e}^{{\frac{d}{{\left.{d}{x}\right.}}{x}^{{{2}{n}}}}}\right]}^{{-\frac{1}{{{{x}_{{0}}^{{{2}{n}}}}}}}}\\=\frac{d}{{{d}{\left(-\frac{1}{{{{x}_{{0}}^{{{2}{n}}}}}}\right)}}}{\left[\frac{d}{{{d}{\left({2}{n}{x}^{{{2}{n}-{1}}}\right)}}}{e}^{{{2}{n}{x}^{{{2}{n}-{1}}}}}\right]}^{{-\frac{1}{{{{x}_{{0}}^{{{2}{n}}}}}}}}\\=\frac{d}{{{d}{\left(-\frac{1}{{{{x}_{{0}}^{{{2}{n}}}}}}\right)}}}{\left({e}^{{{2}{n}{x}^{{{2}{n}-{1}}}}}\right)}^{{-\frac{1}{{{{x}_{{0}}^{{{2}{n}}}}}}}}\\={\left({e}^{{{2}{n}{x}^{{{2}{n}-{1}}}}}\right)}^{{-\frac{1}{{{{x}_{{0}}^{{{2}{n}}}}}}}}\\={\left({e}^{{{2}{n}{x}^{{{2}{n}-{1}}}}}\right)}^{{-\frac{1}{{{{x}_{{0}}^{{{2}{n}}}}}}}}\\={e}^{{-{2}{n}{\left(\frac{x}{{{x}_{{0}}}}\right)}^{{{2}{n}}}\frac{1}{{x}}}}$

In the first case, I immediately applied d/dx.

In the second case, I substituted x/x0 =: z and applied d/dz.

In the third case, I explicitly expanded the expression as nested derivates to show the chain rule, then computed the partial derivations starting from the innermost bracket and progressing outwards - that should be exactly the same as in the first case, it's just written out explicitly what one does mentally.

What is the issue here? I was surprised to get an additional factor of 1/x in the first case, but the third case looks completely different.

Comment: Can you use $\LaTeX$?

Comment: I don't know LaTeX, but I found a nice [online converter](https://www.intmath.com/help/asciimath-input-latex-katex-output.php) for ASCII to TeX! ;)

Comment: Nooo...some brackets are still wrong. Just a minute.....

Comment: Warning: $(e^{x})^n = e^{nx} ≠ e^{x^n} = e^{(x^n)}$

Comment: God...I just wasted one hour trying to convert the third equation from ASCII to TeX. Why does Math SE not have a WYSIWYG formula editor? LaTeX is the single most significant productivity killer of humanity, virtually not a single human being has so far benefited from typing TeX code by hand. And I'm not even joking

Comment: @LL3.14: Thanks for this bit, could you point me to the formula where I did this mistake (1/2/3)?

Comment: @LL3.14: Okay, I suppose you're referring to version 3

Comment: Yes, it is more clear since you updated. About LaTeX: It is just a question of habit. As soon as you are used to it, typing code is really faster than wysiwyg. Even more because mathematicians have a lot of notation and symbols. I have an app that allows me to type latex code in email also for example. But this is not the place to talk about that ...

Comment: @LL3.14: I understand, it's probably the same with most things (i.e. for complicated issues, it is often more powerful to use the low-level language). By the way - even though the correctness of solution #1 has been confirmed - could you briefly points to the step in solution #3 to which your Warning applies? Since #3 is the most explicit one, I'd like to see what went wrong there... Muchas grazioso

Comment: PS.: I suspect that #3 might look a bit strange/unorthodox for mathematicians, as doing this "d/dx juggling" is more of a physicists' thing (i.e. implicitly implying that everything behaves 'nicely')...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your second working, we have $z=\frac{x}{x_0}$,

$$\frac{dz}{dx}=\frac1{x_0}$$

Hence
\begin{align}
f'(x) &= f'(z)\cdot \color{red}{\frac{dz}{dx}}\\&=\frac{1}{x_0}\left( -2n\left( \frac{x}{x_0}\right)^{2n-1}\right)e^{-\left(\frac{x}{x_0} \right)^{2n}}
\\&=\frac{1}{x_0}\left(\frac{x}{x} \right)\left( -2n\left( \frac{x}{x_0}\right)^{2n-1}\right)e^{-\left(\frac{x}{x_0} \right)^{2n}}\\
\\&=\frac{1}{x}\left( -2n\left( \frac{x}{x_0}\right)^{2n}\right)e^{-\left(\frac{x}{x_0} \right)^{2n}}
 \end{align}

hence, the result is consistent.

I can't follow the logic of the third working. I can't understand why do we have $\frac{d}{d\left(-\frac1{x^{2n}} \right)}$

Comment: Yes, I added the x0. But your result **differs** from the second version above by a factor of x0!

Comment: The third version is just the *implicit* chain-rule spelled out *explicitly*, i.e. you first compute the innermost derivative, then the next function, into which it is embedded, then again the next, and the next... I.e. you start with the exponent of the exponential function (derive it), then comes the exponential function itself with the derived argument as argument for the next derivation, then comes the derivation of the whole square bracket, and finally the result is simplified in the last two lines

Comment: The reason I wrote three versions: I first calculated the first version, but wasn't sure. Therefore, I substituted the exponent (basically setting x0 to 1) as a control, but then the factor 1/x was missing. Which is why I did the third version, writing everything down *as explicit and complete as possible* to avoid any error...but got yet another result

Comment: let's ignore the third version for now. let's handle the second version now. Isn't my $f'(x)$ that I computed the same as the first version?

Comment: Mmh...maybe I misunderstood your answer. So you have confirmed the **first** version, not the second (=> *"For your second working..."*)? I thought you had corrected the second one with the substitution (I just resubstituted x/x0 without considering dz/dx), but then we'd get an factor of 1/x0 and not 1/x, which is the one missing in the second version compared to the first.

Comment: yes, I was trying to fix your second version to show that it is equal to the first version. (remark: in a contest, slow response). As for your third version, I do not know where does $\frac{d}{d\left( -\frac1{x_0^{2n}}\right)}$ come from

Comment: Okay, I see. Okay, first regarding your question regarding the strange derivate in the third version: It just means "treat the whole square bracket as the base (=:a), everything in the exponent as the argument (=:b), and do the derivation d/db a^b". It's simply the "outermost layer" of a nested function (e^x)^b with (e^2) =: a

Comment: a^b := (e^c)^b := (e^(x^2n))^b , now do d/dx => d/dc => d/db. It's the chain-rule going from inside to outside

Comment: So I missed the dz/dx in the second version - with it included, 1 and 2 are equal and correct. Great!

Answer (score 0):

$$\displaystyle f={e}^{{-{\left(\frac{x}{{{x}_{{0}}}}\right)}^{{{2}{n}}}}}\implies \log(f)={{-{\left(\frac{x}{{{x}_{{0}}}}\right)}^{{{2}{n}}}}}$$
$$\frac{f'}f=-\frac{2n}{x_0}\left(\frac{x}{x_0}\right)^{2 n-1}$$
$$f'=f \times\frac{f'}f=-\frac{2n}{x_0}\left(\frac{x}{x_0}\right)^{2 n-1}{e}^{{-{\left(\frac{x}{{{x}_{{0}}}}\right)}^{{{2}{n}}}}}$$

Comment: Hi, could you explain this? I'm not sure what is done in line 2+3, as f' is what we're after (hence unknown), but f'/f already seems to be written out explicitly in line 2, but then again calculated in line 3 by multiplying with 1 = f/f